# When building C with dintuils getting cannot find -ltcl83

Tags: c, python-2.7

I'm following this [Building C Extensions with distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html). I have written my demo.c program to build with python.

## demo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("You entered Output: %d\n", number);
    return 0;
```

}

I'm following the step mentioned in `Build C` page with the following commands:

```
gcc -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DMAJOR_VERSION=1 -DMINOR_VERSION=0 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c demo.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/demo.o

gcc -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/demo.o -L/usr/local/lib -ltcl83 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/demo.so
```

When I'm executing the second getting the following error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl83
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not able to `import the demo in the python interpreter`.

Comment: The linker `ld` cannot find the library libtcl83, try to assign the correct path to it. Use -L to assign the directory where libtcl83 is.

Comment: I have used the whereis ltcl83 to find ltcl83. I'm not able to find that package. Do i need to install ?

Comment: I have /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so in my linux system. In my case, I would modify your second gcc command to `-ltcl8.5`.